# ¿De que sirve poner el atributo value en una etiqueta <button>?

Tags: html

Miren ya se que  el atributo **value** es para  Definir el valor predeterminado a ser mostrado al cargar la página. Pero a que se refiere con valor predeterminado en la etiqueta **button** si no le cambia el nombre al boton, ¿es algo relacionado con el Backend?

Aqui el codigo:

`<button type="reset" value="restablecer" >resetear</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la especificación de la W3C que puede ser consultada aquí [specification button](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/the-button-element.html#attr-button-value)

El atributo `value` sirve para fines del envío del formulario, sin embargo viene una nota importante

**NOTA IMPORTANTE**

> El botón y su valor solo son incluidos en el envío del formulario si
>   el botón mismo fue usado para inicial izar el envío del formulario

Así mismo debe quedar claro que el atributo `value` establece un valor por defecto para el *input element*

Toma en cuenta lo siguiente.

Para declarar un botón lo puedes hacer de este modo

```
<input type="button" value="clic me" />
```

Donde como puedes observar el atributo `value` define un valor en formato de cadena de texto que aparecerá por defecto en la declaración anterior

Mas allá de eso ahora declarar el botón de este modo

```
<button>clic me</button>
```

Dará el mismo resultado, sin embargo como ahora estamos usando el tag `button` que esta pensado para la declarativa de un elemento botón, el atributo `value` no lo aplicaría.

Al final como puedes observar tenemos lo siguiente

- Existe mas de un modo de declarar un input de tipo *button*
- Si usas el input entonces para que le aparezca un texto por defecto deberás el atributo `value`
- Si usas la tag `button` entonces el texto que pongas entre la etiqueta de apertura y cierre aparecerá igualando lo que en parte hace `value` en el caso anterior

Answer (score 0):

Sí, mira te pongo un ejemplo en laravel, la parte del backend (dentro del controlador) cuando tu tienes un formulario con varios botones como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu puedes ponerle un id a todos y luego ponerle un value distinto, de tal manera que puedas a traves de un switch invocar segun cada case del value.

```
<button type="submit" id="caso" value="asignar" >asignar</button>
<button type="submit" id="caso" value="remover" >remover</button>
<button type="submit" id="caso" value="anular" >anular</button>
<button type="submit" id="caso" value="devolucion" >devolucion</button>
```

De esta manera.

Comment: Oye bro no entendi muy bien , osea que el value sirve para identificar al boton  como  una variable al usar la sentencia Switch en un lenguaje de programación